# Dirichlet class number formula

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, l-functions

The way the class number formula for Dirichlet L-functions is always proved in modern textbooks and notes is

1. You prove the general class number formula for $\zeta_K(s)$.
2. You prove that for quadratic fields, $\zeta_K(s)=\zeta(s)L(s,\chi)$.
3. Use 1. and 2. to evaluate $L(1,\chi)$.

Dirichlet proved the same formula for $L(1,\chi)$ before Dedekind proved the formula for $\zeta_K(s)$. I hear the he used the theory of quadratic forms.

> **Is there a proof of the formula for $L(1,\chi)$ in the language of ideals which doesn't use the class number formula for $\zeta_K(1)$ or the theory of quadratic forms?**

Comment: you looked at https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/11/28/245a-supplement-1-a-little-bit-of-algebraic-number-theory-optional/#more-7863 ?

Comment: Dirichlet wrote a textbook, that has been translated into English, and is not too hard to read.  Probably it follows his original proof closely.